# Como pegar o extensão de um arquivo?

Tags: html, jsp, file-upload

Estou usando JSP e HTML e preciso selecionar um arquivo e saber a extensão dele.

A única maneira que sei abrir um arquivo é com `input file` mas com ela não consigo pegar a extensão.

Como eu posso obter esse resultado?

Comment: Diretório ou extensão? No cliente ou no servidor?

Comment: vou usar o arquivo, mas pra isso preciso saber qual é a extensão...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Eu acredito que você quer pegar isso antes de enviar alguma informação para o servidor então fiz esse exemplo.

```
<input type="file" name="arquivo" id="arquivo" />
<div id="DivExtensao"></div>
<script>
    //Função será executada quando a página estiver totalmente carregada 
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        //Vincular um evento no input type="file" de name = "arquivo"
        //Evento responsável por qualquer mudança no conteudo do input file
        $("#arquivo").change(function(e) {
           //pegando valor do input file
           var value = $(this).val();
           //comando split responsável na criação de um array de string 
           var values = value.split('.'); 
           if (values.length > 0){
               //pega o ultimo elemento do array que é a extensão
               $("#DivExtensao").html(values[values.length - 1]);
           } else {
               $("#DivExtensao").empty();
           }
        });     
    });     
</script>
```

*Referências:*

- [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
- [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
- [split javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)
- [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: desculpe minha ignorancia, mas vc poderia comentar as linhas... não entendi direito como funciona o seu codigo

Comment: @user7569, eu fiz uma breve descrição sob os itens que achei mais pertinentes, e coloquei um item `Referencias` que você pode ler para que te esclareça melhor ... espero ter ajudado

Comment: muito obrigado... ajudou muito!

Answer (score 1):

No trecho de código abaixo, você obtem de forma mais simples a extensão do arquivo:

```
 extensao =($("#arquivo").substring(arquivo.lastIndexOf("."))).toLowerCase();
```

Eu utilizo este código para validar as extensões permitidas para o meu sistema com a função abaixo:

```
function verificaExtensaoArquivo(arquivo) { 
       extensoes_permitidas = new Array(".pdf", ".png", ".tif", ".tiff", ".bmp", ".jpeg", ".jpg"); 
       extensao = (arquivo.substring(arquivo.lastIndexOf("."))).toLowerCase();
       permite = false;   
          $(extensoes_permitidas).each(function(i){
             if (extensoes_permitidas[i] == extensao) {
                permite = true; 
                return false; 
             } 

          });
        if(!permite){
            alert("EXTENSÃO DO ARQUIVO NÃO PERMITIDA!");
            return false;  
        } 
      return true;      
   }
```